# Why is the DenseNet official implementation different to the paper?

Tags: convolutional-neural-network, pytorch

I've tried to implement DenseNet from scratch (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.06993.pdf), but have run into some confusion after finding the official PyTorch implementation of DenseNet (https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/torchvision/models/densenet.py) and the .lua implementation by the author (https://github.com/liuzhuang13/DenseNet/blob/master/models/densenet.lua).

Here are my doubts:

- In the paper, the first layers a BN-ReLU-Conv(7x7, stride=2, padding=3) followed by an AvgPool(3x3, stride=2, padding=1). However, in the official PyTorch implementation, the first layer is Conv(7x7, stride=2, padding=3)-BN-ReLU. Why is this the case? (see line 168 of PyTorch github link).
- Further, in the .lua implementation there are different options depending on the dataset that is being used. For example, the CIFAR dataset has the first Conv layer as Conv(3x3, stride=1, padding=1) (presumably because the image sizes are only 32x32). This makes sense intuitively, however shouldn't there be an option given to the user to specify depending on their image size?
- In the PyTorch model official implementation, there is a BN step right after the last transition layer, followed by a ReLU. These occur before the global pooling. However, in the paper there are no intermediate steps before the pooling.
- Finally, the weirdest thing about the official PyTorch implementation is that there is no softmax function applied to the Dense layer at the end (once again, unlike in the paper). Is this typically something model builders are expected to add on their own?

Comment: The last point: The [pytorch documentation page](https://pytorch.org/hub/pytorch_vision_densenet/) expects the programmer to use softmax manually on the final outputs (presumably this makes the model more general)

Comment: The first point: Both in Lua implementation and Pytorch, the densenet  initial layer is based on ResNet with Colv2D->BN->ReLU (line 101 of Lua link)

Comment: The paper does not provide all the implementation details, that is why the Lua implementation is provided. So dont expect the paper to mention everything implementation-wise

Comment: Do u know why the initial layer is based on ResNet?

Comment: Presumably because DenseNet was inspired and is a variation of other nets like ResNet. This is mentioned in the paper